# Why does the pytest-threadleak fixture fail for daemon threads?

Tags: pytest

I just added a pytest server fixture that spawns a daemon thread to use for tests over a session.

However, this causes the pytest plugin pytest-threadleak to fail. Daemon threads should automatically terminate when the caller finishes.

In the source https://github.com/nirs/pytest-threadleak/blob/master/test_threadleak.py they use a daemon thread as a true positive for thread leaking?